# ifelse Declaration or statement expected

Tags: switch-statement, declaration

```
function resp (){
  if (distance<0);{
var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode("Yes");
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("inda");
    element.appendChild(para);}
else{
var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode("No, time left:");
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("inda");
    element.appendChild(para);}  
}
```

Why does it give me the error: Declaration or statement expected

Comment: Potentially because of the `;` after the `if`. I wouldn't expect an error from that, but that does break your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (distance<0);{
```

-->

```
if (distance<0) {
```

It's easier to find such problem if you have an ide like webstorm or visual studio code.

Your code in pretty printed form:

```
function resp() {
    if (distance < 0) {
        var para = document.createElement("p");
        var node = document.createTextNode("Yes");
        para.appendChild(node);
        var element = document.getElementById("inda");
        element.appendChild(para);
    } else {
        var para = document.createElement("p");
        var node = document.createTextNode("No, time left:");
        para.appendChild(node);
        var element = document.getElementById("inda");
        element.appendChild(para);
    }
}
```

Your code after little refactoring:

```
function resp() {
    const label = (distance < 0) ? 'Yes' : 'No, time left:';
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode(label);
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("inda");
    element.appendChild(para);
}
```